# All browsers disabled after attempting to install Tor

Tags: firefox, chromium, browser, tor

I've been using Chromium and Firefox for quite a while. Ubuntu and browsers worked perfectly for a long time. Downloaded Tor browser from the Ubuntu software page. It would not finish installation. Error message said, "You may be under attack or have bad internet connectivity." I thought it was just an installation issue. Put it on the "figure it out later" list and moved on. Next couple days Chromium started crashing, especially if I had Firefox open at the same time. Didn't think much of it at first. When it became a pattern, I uninstalled the Tor browser thinking there might be a connection. After uninstalling Tor, the icon didn't go away until two or three reboots. Then, Chromium would not boot at all, and Firefox had all of it's bookmarks removed. Firefox still can access the internet, but will not save bookmarks or allow setting to be altered. I just found I cannot open Libre spreadsheets.

Answer (score -1):

I upgraded from 16.04 to 16.10 and that seems to have fixed everything.